# Trouble theming Ubercart's cart page (Drupal 7) using hook_theme

Tags: 7, hooks, theming, ubercart

Ubercart's **uc_cart** module offers a 'cart' page which I'm willing to have a theme/template. What I did is added following in `mymodule_theme()`:

```
    'uc_cart_view' => array(
        'render element' => 'page', // IS THIS CORRECT?
        'template' => 'cart', // Located in mymodule/templates/cart.tpl.php
        'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/templates', 
    ),
```

But No luck!

**My Question:**

Shall I have some other value for `render element` key? Or shall I have a `variables` entry? I tried with `variables` with an empty array instead of `render element` entry but no luck.

Here goes some more information about Ubercart's uc_cart module so that you can help me solving this issue:

**For Your Consideration**

Portion from `uc_cart_menu`:

```
$items['cart'] = array(
    'title' => 'Shopping cart',
    'description' => 'View/modify the contents of your shopping cart or proceed to checkout.',
    'page callback' => 'uc_cart_view',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'file' => 'uc_cart.pages.inc',
  );
```

So I figured out I should use my custom template for `uc_cart_view`. This `uc_cart_view()` is a function in *uc_cart.pages.inc* page, I've pasted the function [here](http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/515) for your convenience.

Any help on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[uc_cart_view()](http://api.ubercart.me/api/drupal/ubercart!uc_cart!uc_cart.pages.inc/function/uc_cart_view/7) is not a form builder; it is a page callback. As such, `theme_uc_cart_view()` is not automatically called for `uc_cart_view()`. It is the page callback that needs to call the necessary theme function, or refer it such as in the following code.

```
  if (empty($items)) {
    return array(
      '#theme' => 'uc_empty_cart',
    );
  }
```

What you can do is the following:

- Implement [hook_menu_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) to alter the page callback invoked for http://example.com/cart.

  ```
  function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
    if (isset($items['cart'])) {
      $items['cart']['page callback'] = 'mymodule_cart_view';
    }
  }
  ```
- Implement the page callback to output the content as you want it to be.

I cannot suggest the code to write for `mymodule_cart_view()`. Looking at the code used from `uc_cart_view()`, I notice the main part is the following one.

```
  // Load the array of shopping cart items.
  $items = uc_cart_get_contents();

  // Display the empty cart page if there are no items in the cart.
  if (empty($items)) {
    return array(
      '#theme' => 'uc_empty_cart',
    );
  }

  $build = array();
  // Load through the cart panes...
  foreach (uc_cart_cart_pane_list($items) as $id => $pane) {
    // If the pane is enabled...
    if ($pane['enabled']) {
      // Add its output to the cart view.
      $build[$id] = $pane['body'];
    }
  }
```

What a page callback can return, in Drupal 7 is:

- a string containing the markup to output
- an array accepted from [drupal_render()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_render/7), such as the following ones

  ```
  $build = array(
    '#theme' => 'node', 
    '#node' => $node, 
    '#view_mode' => $view_mode, 
    '#language' => $langcode,
  );
  ```

  ```
  $block = array(
    '#markup' => '<em>' . t('There are no rows matching the selected criteria') . '</em>'.
  );
  ```

  ```
  $styles = array(
    '#type' => 'styles', 
    '#items' => $css,
  );
  ```

As side note, in your theme definition, the template filename cannot be "cart"; as the template file is for "uc_cart_view" you can report it to be "uc_cart_view" or "uc-cart-view." Any other filenames are not accepted, from Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

```
$items['uc_cart_view_form'] = array(
    'template' => 'cart/uc-cart-view-form',
    'arguments' => array('form' => NULL),
 );
```

Means you should use `uc_cart_view_form`

Comment: Why? I'm willing to change http://mysite/cart page - should not it means that I should have a template for 'uc_cart_view'?